# Python/Django Save scraped data automatically to my database

Tags: python, django

I would like to save the links scraped to be save in my database so that on subsequent run, it only scrapes and append only new links to the list.

This is my code below but  at the end of the day my database is empty. What changes can I make to overcome this? Thanks in advance

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2, sys
import urlparse
import re
from listing.models import jobLinks

#this function extract the links
def businessghana():
    site = "http://www.businessghana.com/portal/jobs"
    hdr = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    req = urllib2.Request(site, headers=hdr)
    jobpass = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(jobpass)
    for tag in soup.find_all('a', href = True):
        tag['href'] = urlparse.urljoin('http://www.businessghana.com/portal/', tag['href'])
    return map(str, soup.find_all('a', href = re.compile('.getJobInfo')))

# result from businssghana() saved to a variable to make them iterable as a list

all_links  = businessghana()

#this function should be saving the links to the database unless the link already exist
def save_new_links(all_links):
    current_links = jobLinks.objects.all()
    for i in all_links:
        if i not in current_links:
            jobLinks.objects.create(url=i)

# I called the above function here hoping that it will save to database
save_new_links(all_links)

# return my httpResponse with this function
def display_links(request):
    name = all_links()     
    return render_to_response('jobs.html', {'name' : name})
```

My django models.py looks like this:

```
from django.db import models

class jobLinks(models.Model):
    links = models.URLField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date retrieved')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.links
```

Comment: Do you have `debug = True`? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems with your code. First, the `jobLinks` model has no `url` field. You should use `links=i` in the `create()` statement instead. Second, you're checking whether a string, the url, is in a QuerySet. This will never be the case, because the elements of a QuerySet are objects of a model class, in your case, `jobLinks` objects. Instead, you could do something like this:

```
def save_new_links(all_links):
    new_links = []
    for i in all_links:
        if not jobLinks.objects.filter(links=i):
            new_links.append(jobLinks(links=i))
    jobLinks.objects.bulk_create(new_links)
```

I would also recommend that in the future, you use singular words for your models. For example, I would call the model `jobLink` and the field `link` in this case.